# How do I get the Google oauth to open "by flask" instead of by terminal?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

I have a python script which authenticates with google with this code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser])
flags = parser.parse_args()

storage = Storage('credentials.dat')
credentials = storage.get()

if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, flags)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
```

This code is mostly directly from an example at Google Developers site. This is working, I get access, but it does not looks so nice. My application is based on Flask. I want the "allow this app" authentication page to be opened from the web view (when visiting 127.0.0.1) and not directly from the terminal which is happening now. I hope that I explained the problem enough. How should I solve this?